# How to mask out parts of an object?

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to draw mask to hide the ground of my tunnel so that it looks far back and not at the edge of the cliff? It would be a simple thing to do in After Effects but I would need to transfer all the camera tracking data and I don't really want to do that for something so simple.

[image]

Comment: Are you rendering with depth of field?

Comment: No, I will do that in compositing. I just need the edge of the mountain to cover the tunnel's ground so that the placement looks right.

Comment: Ohhh gotcha, I misunderstood

Comment: No worries. Thanks for trying!

Comment: do you mean in the vse? there is a mask you can use...

Comment: Well I was hoping that I could create a shape that follows the cliff's irregular line and set it as a mask so that anything behind this shape would be invisible, which in my case would be part of the tunnel so that it looks further inside. Or maybe project part of my background video onto geometry?